# Customizing Wygwam & CKEditor to prefill width & height attributes

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, ckeditor, responsive-images

For the latest version of Wygwam, is there a way to:

- When an image is added, prevent the image dialog from automatically filling the width/height of the chosen image's dimensions
- Instead, prefill both the width & height fields with the value "100%"

I'm assuming a custom config file can be created & added to a Wygwam configuration via the Advanced Settings, but not sure of the code to do the two steps above.

Thanks all!